# How can I link the header in the navigation menu with a url?

Tags: html, css, url

I am trying to figure out how to link the header in the navigation menu bar to any url when clicking on the text. When I put the `<a href>` tag around it the header went to left of the screen and changed color, and received an underline. How can I keep the header the way it is but link it to some url?

```
<style>
    body {margin:0;}
    .Header {
        z-index: 100;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000000;
        height: 70px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:680px) {
        .Header.responsive {position: relative;}
        .Header.responsive li.icon {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

    }
    @media (max-width: 960px){
    .Header .headerLogo{
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        width: 86px;
        height: 15px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    }
    .headerLogo{
        text-align: center;
        font-size: small;
        font-style: italic;
        font-family: Verdana;
        color: white;


    }
</style>
<body>

<div class="Header" id="myHeader">
    <a class = "headerLogo">
        <h1>Lunation Boards</h1>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
<body>
```

so I updated my code, but I am getting an issue where the mouse turns into a hand (to click the header) throughout the whole navigation menu bar instead of just on the header. Code is below.

```
 <div class="Header" id="myHeader">
        <a class = "headerLogo">
            <a href="file:///C:/Noah's%20stuff/LunationBoards/Home.html" ><h1 style="color:white; font-family: Verdana; font-style: italic; font-size: x-large;
            text-align: center;">Lunation Boards</h1></a>
            <style>
                a{text-decoration: none}
            </style>
```

Comment: You can't have an `<a>` element as a descendant of another `<a>` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the a element *inside* the h1 element:

```
<h1 class="headerLogo">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com">Lunation Boards</a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Then how would I link to lets say, facebook.com?

Comment: The issue is that once I do that, it changes the header color to purple and underlines it, and aligns it to the left instead of in the center

Comment: It may help others finding this question if you show your final code also.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will apply certain styles to links by default. In order to get rid of the underline, you can use `text-decoration: none`, and then you can set the colour by using `color: #000` or whatever other colour you want.

## CSS

```
.headerLogo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: whatevercolouryouwant;
  etc: etc;
}
```